# length = raw_input("what is the length of all you walls added together? ") height = raw_input("what is the height of your room? ")

Tags: python

```
length = raw_input("what is the length of all you walls added together? ")
height = raw_input("what is the height of your room? ")
area = height*length
paint = raw_input("what paint would you like to use luxury paint, Standard quality, Economy quality? ")
if paint == "LP":
    answer = 2*area 
    print answer
if paint == "SQ":
    answer = 1.25*area  
    print answer
if paint == "EQ":
    answer = 0.55*area  
    print answer
```

This is the code it keeps saying that "`typeerror: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`" does anyone have any idea?

i have another problem i need to set an range of what answers i can have which is between 2 and 25 for length and 1 and 6 for height
 `while (length < 2) or (length > 25):
    wrong = raw_input("invalid number please try again? ") 
while (height < 1) or (height > 6):
    wrong = raw_input("invalid number please try again? ")`
this doesn't work it just says invalid number for everything

Comment: `height` is a string. `length` is a string. What do you expect `string * string` to do?

Comment: you're not binding the user inputs as `int` or `float`

Comment: i need them to be integers there supposed to be multiplied then what paint would they need would times that and then you would get a price for how much it is to paint

Answer (score 2):

Convert the height and length to integers or floats, like this:

```
length = float(raw_input("what is the length of all you walls added together? "))
height = float(raw_input("what is the height of your room? "))
```

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: @jaii1000 Mark it accepted so Community does not bump it as an unanswered question.

Comment: my question hasn't been answered

Comment: Ask a new question, @jaii1000, this one has been closed.